# PHPUnit coverage report keeps returning Sample Content

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

We're currently using PHPUnit (*both PHPUnit 7.1.5 & 7.4.5 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors*) to unittest out code. We have multiple test suites done and want to run a coverage report.

I can run the test just fine and as expected. Now, with xdebug enabled and the coverage-html flag I run it again, but instead of a nice report, I get a "Big Table Sorting - 1000 Rows" table with 1000 rows of 'Sample Content' as output in the console and no reports in the given directory.

I can't find any related issues via Google, anyone know how to fix this?

Excecuted command:

```
php bin/phpunit --filter ClassnameTest::testMethodname --coverage-html ./reports/20191103
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>rowsorter.js - big table</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/RowSorter.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style>
table {width: 80%; font-size: 14px; font-family: tahoma, arial, sans-serif;}
table thead th {background-color: #ccc; padding: 5px 8px;}
table td {background-color: #ddd; padding: 5px 8px;}

table.sorting-table {cursor: move;}
table tr.sorting-row td {background-color: #8b8;}
table td.div {padding: 0;}
table td.div > div {background-color: #b88;line-height:2;}
</style>

<table class="sample_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Big Table Sorting - 1000 Rows</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td>Row 0</td>
            <td>Sample Content 0</td>
            <td class="div"><div><div><span>Inner Elements 0</span></div></div></td>
            <td>Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Row 1</td>
            <td>Sample Content 1</td>
            <td class="div"><div><div><span>Inner Elements 1</span></div></div></td>
            <td>Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Row 2</td>
            <td>Sample Content 2</td>
            <td class="div"><div><div><span>Inner Elements 2</span></div></div></td>
            <td>Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Row 3</td>
            <td>Sample Content 3</td>
            <td class="div"><div><div><span>Inner Elements 3</span></div></div></td>
            <td>Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Row 4</td>
            <td>Sample Content 4</td>
            <td class="div"><div><div><span>Inner Elements 4</span></div></div></td>
            <td>Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Row 5</td>
            <td>Sample Content 5</td>
            <td class="div"><div><div><span>Inner Elements 5</span></div></div></td>
            <td>Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content Sample Content</td>
        </tr>
           
        
        <!-- .. up to 1000 .. -->
        
        </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><button type="button" onclick="RowSorter.destroy('.sample_table');">Destroy RowSorter</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
RowSorter(".sample_table");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks like this: https://github.com/arteyazilim/rowsorter/blob/96d55ed1a6294fe58e6d17948942856b4f6ae11c/examples/big_table.php - is that GitHub repo in your project or vendors?

Comment: We have it installed via composer :)

Comment: Well that's part of the mystery solved. I'd put `debug_print_backtrace(); die;` in that file - and see why/how it's being sourced. Since the file itself doesn't halt processing (i.e. even if it's loaded the coverage report aught to still be generated correctly, but apparently isn't) there may yet be more steps before coverage reports work.

Comment: To the close voter, what more info do you need?

Comment: I voted to close as it's not possible to answer the question. You need to identify why/how that file is being sourced and how that is responsible for (apparently) halting phpunit. In short, the question needs to be clearer or provide a reproducible problem.

Comment: We are one step closer to finding out why. It appears to do with an odd yarn config in Docker